# Update table values based on a subquery from another database

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to dynamically subquery another database (db2) and update current table (db1.t1) based on the results.  The field Location (db1.t1.location) determines which database (db2) should be.  I typically accomplish this using vba however, I'm looping through each row.  Quite simply i'm 100% the sql equivalent would be much more efficient.

What i'd like to do is have 2 databases

1. DB1
2. DB2 (where the database would be selected based on value in DB1)

e.g. if db1.dbo.t1.location='North' then DB2 name='DBNorth', if db1.dbo.t1.location='South' then DB2 name='DBSouth'.

Not sure of where to begin to join / update fields.

The following is what i'm trying to accomplish:

- Establish which database will be joined based on value in row of db1.dbo.t1
- join databases based on location, unique_identifier (db1.dbo.t1.location, 
  db1.dbo.t1.unique_identifer)
- if record exists in db2 that contains location, unique identifer from db1 then 
  update db1.dbo.t1.status to 1 else 0

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

i don't think you can join databases(though am not 100% sure)...but
to use tables from a diferrent database you can use dbname..tablename.
so you can inner join them on that.
may be you can try:

```
select * from db1..t1 d1 inner join db2..t1 d2 on d1.location=d2.location
```

and also in your case, as the database names are in database db1, you can first extract them to a temp table and  then loop through the temp table, updating your data in the loop

Answer (score -1):

You could build your query with a string and use exec to execute it.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: @Ian would you be able to provide a bit more direction based on the information i provided? haven't done much work with variables in SQL.